# AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer is missing from my Maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

For whatever reason, maven did not build the

```
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
```

class. Bellow are the relevant parts of my pom.xml that contains necessary spring dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

The build as shown in eclipse for the relevant directory looks like:

[image]

It should be built under the package org.springframework.web.servlet.support. Am I missing something? How can rebuild maven dependencies to get this class?

Comment: Which spring version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.1.1

Comment: This class was added in 3.2 so you will not find it in Spring 3.1.

Comment: If you submit that as an answer I will accept it. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convenience subclasses for `WebAplicationInitializer`s were added in Spring 3.2.x so upgrade so one of the 3.2 version. (Currently 3.2.5.RELEASE is the latest).